# Mongodb - Multiple counts vs Aggregation framework performance

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo db with about 200K documents. The schema of documents is something like

```
doc : {
    'class' : String,
    'data' : {}   
}
```

Class can be a, b or c.

I need to know how many documents I have per class.

What query have a better performance? Make the query using aggregation framework or make 3 querys, each counting the documents for the different classes?

Thanks!

Comment: The best way is by experiment. `$group` will not use index if any

Comment: Agree with orid. Even if there was a good theoretical answer, you would have to provide a full example, query patterns, etc. The question, as it stands, is like "how to build house. must have 2 windows. use brick?"

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/), for a few simple reasons:

- It's quick and can use indexes (especially if you avoid using $project before grouping).
- It's a single call to mongod. Simple, clean, you can monitor it easily.
- If you add more classes in the future, you will not have to change the aggregation chain **at all**. In contrast, if you choose to make different count statements, you will have to add one or more statements and you will also have to change application code to handle the results.